# Applying consistent symbology across all fields of layer using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, symbology

I have a shapefile of a country with 50 fields. Each field contains values (-3 to 3) for a particular month. I would like to create a for loop that iterates through the fields, updates the map, uses a common symbology and exports to a PNG file.

The symbology I would like to use is one color per number. -3 = dark orange, -2 = light orange, -1 = light yellow, 0 = grey, 1 = light green, 2 = dark green, 3 = very dark green. I've assigned these colors to the layer in the .mxd, and created a .lyr.

So far, I have this:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r'path/to/mxd')
shp = r'path/to/country_shapefile'
outdir = r'path/to/out/directory'
symbology = r'path/to/symbology.lyr'

df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
fields = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(shp)]
fields = fields(17:len(fields) # I only need to display the data in fields 17 onwards
layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, 'country')[0]
symbol = layer.symbology

for field in fields:
    symbol.valueField = field
    symbol.classValues = [-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3] # The range of values in the symbology
    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(layer, symbology)
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.RefreshTOC()
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, outdir+'\\'+field+".png")

---
```

When I try this, I get a map displaying the values in every field, but not with the correct symbology.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: Hi Midavalo, I've edited my question to describe the symbology in a bit more detail. Let me know if this is still unclear?

Comment: Apply symbology from layer http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006n000000 takes two arguments, neither of which is field and symbol, the first is the layer to set and the 2nd is the layer (or layer file) with the symbology to copy from.

Comment: Hi @MichaelStimson, could you kindly indicate how to modify the current code based on your suggestion?

Comment: Do you have a layer with the correct symbology, preferably saved as a layer file? arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(layer, r'c:\some\path\SymbolLayer.lyr') should do it (change the path to match).

Comment: @MichaelStimson It's not the solution of asker. Asker wants to change symbology based on the fields automatically.

Comment: @K2609 I'm not sure what you are wanting to do can be done.  Every time you use the Apply Symbology from Layer it will reset your symbology field to match the layer you are applying from.  When you change the symbology field it resets the symbology to default.  Your script as-is doesn't appear to work for me (errors) but with modification I can get it to output PNG files, but not with different symbology

Comment: In fact a quick search for similar questions find several with no real solution (but there are a couple of suggested work arounds)

Comment: @Midavalo, can you point me to some of the work arounds? I've been trying to play with the code, but I either get the wrong symbology (but the right field values), or the right symbology (with the wrong field values - just repeating the map from the mxd).

Comment: I have expanded the idea given in an answer to [Changing Field Name/Apply Symbology from layer using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154417/changing-field-name-apply-symbology-from-layer-using-arcpy) into an answer that I think may suit your requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, I don't think you can use `arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management()` and `symbol.valueField` to change the field but keep the same symbols.

A possible work-around would be to create a new field to store your values in for symbolising.  This field could be temporary if you can't leave it in the shapefile, or alternatively if you can't modify the shapefile you could copy the entire dataset to an `in_memory` layer for processing purposes.

The idea is to loop through your different fields and copy the values to your symbology field.  Your symbology properties will then stay the same, but the actual values on the feature will change each time the script loops.

Create your layer file first, with the symbology you want to use (set to a field called `temp_field` or whatever you want to call your temporary field

Sample Data:
[image]

Layer file symbology properties:
[image]

```
import arcpy, os
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
outdir = r"C:\GIS\SE\SymOutput"
symLayer = r'C:\GIS\SE\LayerToSymboliseFrom.lyr'
myLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0]
arcpy.AddField_management(myLayer,'temp_field', "SHORT")
fields = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(myLayer) if field.name <> 'temp_field']
fields = fields[2:len(fields)]
for field in fields:
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(myLayer, "temp_field", "!{0}!".format(field), "PYTHON_9.3")
    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(myLayer, symLayer)
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, os.path.join(outdir, "{0}.png".format(field)))
arcpy.DeleteField_management(myLayer, 'temp_field')
```

Screenshots showing the output:

Field 1:
[image]

Field 2:
[image]

Field 3:
[image]

Comment: Hi Midavalo! This is exactly what I am after. Unfortunately when I try to replicate your code, I get the same map for all the fields (e.g. the Field 1 map in your case, repeated over and over). Do you know why this may be the case?

Comment: Your saved Layer file containing the symbology must have the symbology set to use the name of the temporary field.  You may need to create a dummy shapefile with this field present in order to select that field name

Answer (score 0):

here are a few remarks to move further (see my comments on your script):

```
for field in fields: # this returns some fields objects, but you need to work with fields names (this can be managed here or later)
    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(layer, symLayer) #symLayer is a lyr file with your symbology 
    layer.symbology.valueField = field.name #this must be changed AFTER you import the symbology, and I use the name of the field
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.RefreshTOC()
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, outdir+'\\'+field.name+".png")#here again, use fields' name
```

Comment: In my testing it seemed that `layer.symbology.valueField = field.name` reset the symbology that had been set in the line above (`arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management()`)